# How to implement pagination while searching data from kusto using python library

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer

I have written one simple code where i'm trying to get data from kusto table using python sdks. Is there anyway i can get pagination response for the data ?

```
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table

def execute_kusto_query(authentication, cluster: str, database: str, query: str, tenant_id: str, client_id: str = None, client_secret: str  = None, page_size: int = 10):

try:
    if authentication == 'client_secret':
        connection_string = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(
            cluster,
            client_id,
            client_secret,
            authority_id=f"{tenant_id}"
        )
    elif authentication == 'managed_identity':
        connection_string = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_managed_service_identity_authentication(cluster)                    
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid authentication method.")
    
    with KustoClient(connection_string) as client:
        response = client.execute_query(database, query)
        Dataframe = dataframe_from_result_table(response.primary_results[0])
        return(Dataframe)

except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Error executing Kusto query: {str(ex)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination can be achieved by using [Stored Query Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results#pagination).